# Live streaming using videojs-record and videojs

Tags: python, vue.js, video.js, videojs-record

I'm trying to make a video chat inside my application, and using videojs-record + videojs to do so. videojs-record to record the webcam (which is already working), and videojs to reproduce the video in the other side. By using the timestamp event, with the `timeSlice` property, I've managed to split the recorded video by each second.

```
this.player = videojs('#myVideo', this.options, () => {});

var player = this.player
var that = this

this.player.on('startRecord', () => {
    that.segment = 0
});

player.on('timestamp', function() {
    if (player.recordedData && player.recordedData.length > 0) {
        var binaryData = player.recordedData[player.recordedData.length - 1]
        that.$emit('dataVideoEvent', {video:binaryData, segment_index:that.segment})
        that.segment += 1
    }
});
```

So I've managed to upload the said segments to Amazon's S3, and have used a Python endpoint to return a HLS file containing the uploaded files:

```
duration = 1
totalDuration = len(list)
string = ('#EXTM3U\n'
            '#EXT-X-PLAYLIST-TYPE:EVENT\n'
            '#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:3600\n'
            '#EXT-X-VERSION:3\n'
            '#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0\n')
ended = False
now = datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=pytz.utc)
for index, obj in enumerate(list):
    url = {retrieving url based in obj}
    string += '#EXTINF:{duration}, no desc\n{url}\n'.format(duration=duration, url=url)
    ended = (obj.created_at.replace(tzinfo=pytz.utc) + timedelta(seconds=10)) < now

if ended:
    string += '#EXT-X-ENDLIST'
```

Although, that HLS file isn't working. The videojs player shows the proper full time of the video, but never starts to play it, and logs no errors. If I try to reproduce the video using [Bitmovin's player demo](http://bitmovin.com/demos/stream-test), it says SOURCE_MANIFEST_INVALID.

I've also tried to create a XML+DASH file instead of a HLS one, but it didn't work as well. And I've also tried to change the videojs-record videoMimeType property to other values, like `video/webm;codecs=vp8,opus` or `video/mp2t;codecs=vp8,opus`, but it also didn't change a thing.

Also, the @action that returns the HLS file has a `renderer_classes` property using that renderer:

```
class HLSRenderer(BaseRenderer):
    media_type = 'application/x-mpegurl'
    format = 'm3u8'
    level_sep = '.'
    header = None
    labels = None
    writer_opts = None

    def render(self, data, media_type=None, renderer_context={}, writer_opts=None):
        return data
```

And at last, I've configured CORS in that way in S3, in case that's relevant:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>HEAD</AllowedMethod>
    <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
    <AllowedHeader>Range</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

And by the way, the @action is usually blocked so only the expected user can see it, but at this moment I've changed its `permission_classes` value to `AllowAny`, so I can test in websites like Bitmovin.

What exactly am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave up and ended up using Jitsi instead of videojs-record. I had to run it with an iframe within Vue, but it succeed where all the rest failed.

I've spent the last 18 days trying to make a live stream by myself, when I could make Jitsi work with my project in almost one single night. I recommend their Docker, it's pretty easy to set up.

https://github.com/jitsi/docker-jitsi-meet